# How can serialize a GPIO list to json?

Tags: json, python-3.x, gpio

I have the following setup

```
LEDS = {"green": 16, "red": 18}

@app.route('/leds/', methods=["GET"])
def api_leds_state():
    return {"green": GPIO.input(LEDS["green"]), "red": GPIO.input(LEDS["red"])}
```

which returns the pins state

```
{
    "green": 0,
    "red": 0
}
```

Unfortunately the code above is hardcoded. How can i get the desired json response with a loop or serialization or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure that's what you're asking for, but here's a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) to overcome the hardcoded keys in your return dict:

```
return {color:GPIO.input(pin) for color, pin in LEDS.items()}
```

Iterating over `LEDS.items()` gives you both the key and value of a pair in `LEDS`, which is what you need to create each new pair in your result dict.